# Sending image data using AJAX and store on server

Tags: php, ajax, html, canvas

PHP isn't receiving data from ajax, I am trying to create image by using canvas HTML5 and store it on my server using PHP, but when I do, I dont receive anything.

image.php:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas width="800" height="420" id="canvas"></canvas>
<script>

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var img  = loadImage('images/quizes/sim.png' ,main);
var img1 = loadImage('images/users/alfred.jpg', main);
var img2 = loadImage('images/users/brynjar.jpg', main);


var imagesLoaded = 0;
function main() {
    imagesLoaded += 1;

    if(imagesLoaded == 3) {

        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 800, 420);

        ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0, 320, 320);

        ctx.drawImage(img2, 480, 0, 320, 320);

    }
}

function loadImage(src, onload) {
    var img = new Image();

    img.onload = onload;
    img.src = src;

    return img;
}

var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

alert(dataURL);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "script.php",
    data: {
        imgBase64: dataURL
    }
}).done(function(o) {
    console.log('saved');
    // If you want the file to be visible in the browser
    // - please modify the callback in javascript. All you
    // need is to return the url to the file, you just saved
    // and than put the image in your browser.
});
</script>
```

And I also have Script.php:

```
$img = $_POST['data'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$fileData = base64_decode($img);
//saving
$fileName = 'photo.png';
file_put_contents($fileName, $fileData);
```

But when I run image.php, $_post['data'] doesn't pick up any data.

Comment: Try to read `$_POST['imgBase64']` variable. If it is empty or not exist, provide the result of `var_dump($_POST)` here.

Comment: Tanks, I did work to read `$_POST['imgBase64']`

Answer (score 0):

You should read data from `$_POST['imgBase64']` variable.